# Proof that square of sum equal to sum of cubes of N.

Tags: natural-numbers

Does exist a proof for this:

> $$(1 + 2 + 3 + 4)^2=1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3$$

Comment: Are you familiar with mathematical induction? There's a "visual proof" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(algebra)#Sum_of_first_n_cubes)

Comment: For the specific example you have given you can simply compute each side.